# Email attachments in SharePoint 2013 blog

Tags: sharepoint-server, email, blog, attachments

I have been trying to display the email attachments in the posts (in the body itself). It is still possible if I go to the ribbon and open it, but is it somehow possible to display it in the body of the post itself. It wouldn't matter even if there was an attachment icon or a hyperlink in the body of the blog post.

Thank you